# HTC One M9 google pixel launcher experience app removel

Tags: uninstallation, htc-one-m9

My HTC One M9 with Android 7.0 will not allow me to uninstall an app which is flashed by TWRP Recovery. Actually its a google pixel launcher experience app by XDA forum.

Comment: if you have flashed zip type of app using twrp, it will be installed as system app. And, system apps can be removed using apps like `titanium backup` which requires root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have made it a system app by flashing so you can not uninstall it via conventional methods. If you are a rooted user then you can remove it via this [system app remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en).